# Measuring sizes by using Emgu haarcascade

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to develop a uniform sizing application which will determine your size whether you are small, medium, large or x-large. The user will be standing in a fixed distance away from the camera and the system will capture a whole body image of the user, and from that image the system will get the measurements needed. My problem here is the getting of detecting of measurement the system detects the same measurement for all user even though their sizes are far from each other. How will I make the detection more accurate?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;

namespace fitting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        HaarCascade UpperBody = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml");
        HaarCascade LowerBody = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_lowerbody.xml");

        Capture camera;
        bool captureProcess = false;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void viewImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            img = camera.QueryFrame();
            if (img == null)
                return;
            CamImageBox.Image = img;
        }

        private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (captureProcess == true)
            {
                string data;

                Application.Idle -= viewImage;
                captureProcess = false;
                SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    img.ToBitmap().Save(dlg.FileName + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    data = dlg.FileName + ".jpg";
                }
                measureImage();
            }
        }

        void measureImage()
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg2 = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg2.Filter = "Image|*.jpg;*png";
            if (dlg2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(dlg2.FileName);
                Image<Gray, Byte> Gray_Frame = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();


/////////////////////////LOWER BODY DETECTION////////////////////////////////
                MCvAvgComp[][] LowerBodyDetect = Gray_Frame.DetectHaarCascade(
                    LowerBody,
                    1.985603925968,
                    0,
                    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                    new Size());

///////////////////HERE IS THE UPPER BODY DETECTION/////////////////////////

                MCvAvgComp[][] UpperBodyDetect = Gray_Frame.DetectHaarCascade(
                    UpperBody,
                    1.3,
                    5,
                    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                    new Size());


/////////////////////////DRAWING OF RECTANGLE ON DETECTED UPPER BODY///////////////////
                try
                {
                    frame.Draw(UpperBodyDetect[0][0].rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                    double width = (UpperBodyDetect[0][0].rect.Width);
                    textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString(width));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
///////////////////////DRAWING OF RECTANGLE ON DETECTED LOWER BODY///////////////////
                try
                {
                    frame.Draw(LowerBodyDetect[0][0].rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                CamImageBox.Image = frame;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool useCam = false;

            if (!useCam)
                measureImage();
            else {
                try
                {
                    camera = new Capture();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                    return;
                }
                Application.Idle += viewImage;
                captureProcess = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```